# Do I have recourse against my employer for broadcasting my suspension to coworkers?

Tags: defamation, workplace, tennessee

I was suspended for a day and the manager sent out an email to at least 13 other people with suspension written on the schedule. What recourse do I have? This is very humiliating to me.

Comment: Which country/state? Was that the extent of the email (did it contain the reason for the suspension, etc)?

Comment: TN. No, it just said suspended. The email said changes need to be made from time to time and included the schedule for the rest if this week and next week.

Answer (score 3):

No. Absent some collective bargaining agreement to the contrary, you have no recourse because you have not been legally wronged. You have no right to privacy in this regard. You have no right to be free of humiliation based upon truthful statements.

If the email is truthful and you were indeed suspended, then the manager is entirely appropriate in sharing that information, and indeed has a need to do so.

You would have no recourse in Tennessee, even if your manager gave a national television interview on your suspension and truthfully stated all reasons for the suspension and threw in statements of opinion disparaging you.

Humiliation is only actionable if it amounts to "outrageous conduct" beyond mere truthful speech (e.g. throwing your clothes in the toilet or secretly putting some self-disparaging statement on the back of your uniform) and was calculated with a specific intent to cause you extraordinary emotional harm that was not necessary for some legitimate purpose.

Comment: This answer presumes that this is an isolated act and not part of a pattern of bullying and harassment

Comment: I don't see any need that the manager has for disclosing the suspension.  If it's necessary to indicate that the employee will be unavailable, forexample for scheduling purposes, that information can be conveyed less precisely by omitting the reason for the unavailability.

Comment: It isn't necessary, and the course taken was relatively polite. But, there is ultimately no actionable right to privacy in this kind of context. A pattern of bullying and harassment is also not, in general, actionable, unless it is a manifestation of discrimination against a protected class or is in retaliation for previous lawful conduct (e.g. trying to organize a union) that is protected by law. The outrageous conduct tort is very narrow.